# Position Google Maps InfoWindow to the right corner

Tags: google-maps

Instead of the default position above the marker , I want the InfoWindow to be open to the top right corner of the map . How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Infowindows may be attached to either a marker object or on the map itself at a sepcified lat,lng. That being said, if you allow users to pan your map, there isn't a good way to put the infowindow at the top-right corner of the map. You can only anchor it to a marker or specific lat,lng. Moving the map will move the infowindow whether it is anchored to a marker or a lat,lng.

One possible thing you could do as a workaround is use custom controls as documented here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls

You can put these custom controls at the top-right corner of the map. Depending on what you were wanting the infowindow to have inside of it, you may be able to use the custom controls in the link above to accomplish what you need. The custom controls are really intended for user interaction, but if you need to have an info-window at the top-right of your map to display information, I believe this would be a good workaround.

I hope this helps!

Comment: can you elaborate on how to do that? I'm looking to just get some info and an image in a box fixed to the top left of the map window